# How to insert a date from a form into a table with mysqli

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I have a table in which there are two fields with date data types.  I am having difficulty inserting a value from a form with the date type into this table.

The php I use to insert:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO JOB_TBL(JT_JOB_DESCRIPTION_FLD, JT_JOB_TITLE_FLD, JT_JOB_POST_DATE_FLD, JT_JOB_CLOSE_DATE_FLD, JT_JOB_POSTER_FLD) 
                VALUES(?, ?, " . $open . "," . $close . ", ?)";

    if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $title, $desc, '1');
```

The form HTML for close and open:

```
 <input type="Date" name="jobOpen">
 <input type="Date" name="jobClose">
```

Not shown is where i pass the resulting post data into the function with the query.  The two fields in question are both date fields with no other constraints.

I have also tried to bind them as strings, but that has not worked.

Thank you.

UPDATE:  The two variables are formatted as "2013-12-04"

Comment: what do u get in $open, $close ? can you show your post variables?

Comment: You should ALWAYS bind any data, not just "try" it.

Comment: original code was bound, changed it since I wasn't 100% sure date was passed as a string (and was trying to solve the problem of the page doing nothing when it wasn't happy)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By default input `type="date"` shows dates as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

You can force it to a UNIX Timestamp using `strtotime($open)` and then setting the columns to a INT(10) type in the database.

You can then retrieve the times using the `date()` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

New Code

```
$open = strtotime($open);
$close = strtotime($close);
$query = "INSERT INTO JOB_TBL(JT_JOB_DESCRIPTION_FLD, JT_JOB_TITLE_FLD, JT_JOB_POST_DATE_FLD, JT_JOB_CLOSE_DATE_FLD, JT_JOB_POSTER_FLD) 
            VALUES(?, ?, " . $open . "," . $close . ", ?)";
```